# delay() jquery не срабатывает

Tags: jquery

```
$('#check_one_hid').css('display','inline-block').delay(10000).css('display','none');
```

нет отсрочки выполнения на заданное время

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout( function () {$('#check_one_hid').css('display','none')},10000);

так попробуйте

Comment: Расширьте ответ - добавьте в него рабочий пример, дайте пояснения.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#check_one_hid').delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
  $(this).css('display', 'inline-block');
  next();
}).delay(1000).hide(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="check_one_hid" style="display: none;">Value</div>
```